# Interconnection between ServiceBus properties AutoDeleteOnIdle and ForwardTo

Tags: azureservicebus

What is the relation between the ServiceBus properties Requires Duplication Detection, AutoDeleteOnIdle and ForwardTo?

1. I have a ServiceBus queue with '*Requires Duplicate Detection*' enabled and *AutoDeleteOnIdle* property set to
   max value, 10675199:2:48:5:4775807
2. I am updating the queue property
   *AutoDeleteOnIdle*  to hold value 2 days
3. Upon setting the *ForwardTo* property to another queue, the *AutoDeleteOnIdle* value gets reset to
   10675199:2:48:5:4775807.
   Clarity on why AutoDeleteOnIdle of '*Requires Duplicate Detection*' enabled queue resets to max value on defining ForwardTo will be of great help.

Comment: What are you using to perform this? A tool or a custom code? The `AutoDeleteOnIdle` should not be affected when you specify auto-forwarding.

Comment: ServiceBusExplorer is the tool i was using to perform the above action. I could observe the same behavior on using a custom implementation too.

Comment: I’ve tried the latest SBE and it works fine. Mind to share the repro code?

Comment: Hi @Sean, This time using latest version of ServiceBusExplorer 4.0.110. I still observe the same behavior described above. Please try this on a queue with 'Requires Duplicate Detection' enabled. I am modifying the question accordingly

Comment: Tried that combination as well, and AutoDeleteOnIdle value is retained.

Answer (score 0):

@SeanFeldman Posting this as a answer as i need to attach images and i could not do so in a comment.
I am using SBE 3.0.4. Please find the screen shots to gain clarity on the scenario.

The queue orders-bulk was initially having  ***AutoDeleteOnIdle*** value 10 days(Image 1). Once i define the ***ForwardTo*** property to another queue say 'order-new' the ***AutoDeleteOnIdle*** gets set to the max value (Image 2)

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

My custom code uses WindowsAzure.ServiceBus to update the Queue properties. I observe same behavior there too.

Comment: version 4.0.110 is the [latest](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/releases/latest)...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. I'll update the documentation to reflect this.

Given the pull semantics of a queue, the ForwardTo operation is set up as a 'receive'. Due to this, a queue that has ForwardTo setup is never really 'idle'.

This is why the value for AutoDeleteOnIdle is reset.

P.S: The 'Requires Duplicate Detection' property plays no part in this logical flow.